# How to keep reading after while loop?

Tags: c++, filestream

I have a .txt file that has a sequence of numbers and spaces on the first line that I wish to read into a vector. Then there is a '$' symbol on the next line. On the line after that is another line containing a sequence of numbers and spaces (like the first) that I'd like to read into another vector. For example

```
1 2 3 4 5
$
4 3 2 1 6
```

I've tried everything but can't keep reading after the initial while loop reads in integers. How do I move past the second line and read the third? Right now It just outputs the first line. Currently, this is my code:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    ifstream file(argv[1]); 
    if (file.is_open() && file.good()){
        int addMe;
        vector<int> addMeList;
        while(file>>addMe){
            cout <<addMe<<endl;
            addMeList.push_back(addMe);
        }

        string skip;
        while(file >> skip)
            cout << skip << endl;

        int searchQuery;
        vector<int> searchQueries;

        while(file>>searchQuery){
            searchQueries.push_back(searchQuery);
        }

        for (int i=0; i<searchQueries.size();i++)
        {
            cout << searchQueries[i]<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

1. The first loop will cause the streams `failbit` to be set (when it attempts to read the `'$'` from the second line). If that bit is set, you can't read more from the stream. You need 
   to [clear](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) the stream state.
2. Once you've done the above, the second loop will read the rest of the file.

One possible solution is to read *lines* instead. Use e.g. [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read a line. Put the line into a [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream), and read the values from that.

Comment: Thanks so much. I used the clear state method just to make the code less clunky with the getline.

Answer (score 0):

The program logic seems to be flawed. Using the  **first** `while` loop you read the **entire** file word-by-word till the very end (not till the end of line), after that trying to read again fails, which is evaluated as `false`, thus it never even gets into the other loops. Instead, consider reading line by line using `getline` and then breaking it into `int`s using `istringstream`.
Here's how I'd improve it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>                  // include this header to use istringstream
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream file("text.txt");      // my test file; Replace with yours 
    if (file.is_open() && file.good()) {

        string lineIn;              // general line to read into
        int i;                      // general int to read into
        vector<int> addMeList;
        // int addMe;               // not needed anymore
        getline(file, lineIn);      // read a line 1
        istringstream istr(lineIn); // string stream we can use to read integers from
        while (istr >> i) {
            cout << i << endl;
            addMeList.push_back(i);
        }


        // string skip;              // not needed anymore 

        getline(file, lineIn);       // skips line 2

        // int searchQuery;          // not needed anymore
        vector<int> searchQueries;

        getline(file, lineIn);       // read a line 2
        istringstream istr2(lineIn); // string stream we can use to read integers from
        while (istr2 >> i) {
            searchQueries.push_back(i);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < searchQueries.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << searchQueries[i] << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input file:

```
1 2 3 4 5
$
4 3 2 1 6
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
4
3
2
1
6
```